# troubleshooting DDNS client installation: ./installer.sh

Tags: software-installation, raspbian

Context:  DDNS client to be installed on Raspbian (Raspberry Pi).  [Online Installation through SSH](https://ownyourbits.com/2017/03/05/dynamic-dns-for-raspbian-with-no-ip-org-installer/) instructions:

First, Clone the repo:

```
git clone https://github.com/nachoparker/nextcloud-raspbian-generator.git
```

Second, Invoke the generic software installer with the script no-ip.sh

```
pi@nextcloudpi:~ $ ./installer.sh no-ip.sh 192.168.8.114
-bash: ./installer.sh: No such file or directory
```

**Question: Where to begin troubleshooting the above error?**

Check clone results:

```
pi@nextcloudpi:~ $ cd ~/nextcloud-raspbian-generator/
pi@nextcloudpi:~/nextcloud-raspbian-generator $ ls -l
total 248
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi pi  2059 Oct 10 19:02 armbian.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 pi pi  3441 Oct 10 19:02 batch.sh
drwxr-xr-x 3 pi pi  4096 Oct 10 19:02 bin
-rwxr-xr-x 1 pi pi  2531 Oct 10 19:02 build-docker.sh
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi pi 10904 Oct 10 19:02 buildlib.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 pi pi  1926 Oct 10 19:02 build-SD-armbian.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 pi pi  1663 Oct 10 19:02 build-SD-berryboot.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 pi pi  4093 Oct 10 19:02 build-SD-rpi.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 pi pi  2038 Oct 10 19:02 build-VM.sh
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi pi 77575 Oct 10 19:02 changelog.md
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi pi    96 Oct 10 19:02 config-bananapi.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi pi    96 Oct 10 19:02 config-odroidxu4.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi pi    12 Oct 10 19:02 config-orangepizeroplus2-h5.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi pi   120 Oct 10 19:02 config-rock64.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi pi   338 Oct 10 19:02 CONTRIBUTING.md
drwxr-xr-x 6 pi pi  4096 Oct 10 19:02 docker
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi pi   287 Oct 10 19:02 docker-compose-armhf.yml
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi pi   264 Oct 10 19:02 docker-compose-nc-armhf.yml
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi pi   347 Oct 10 19:02 docker-compose-ncpdev.yml
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi pi   262 Oct 10 19:02 docker-compose-nc.yml
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi pi   285 Oct 10 19:02 docker-compose.yml
drwxr-xr-x 3 pi pi  4096 Oct 10 19:02 etc
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi pi  3202 Oct 10 19:02 install.sh
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi pi  5789 Oct 10 19:02 lamp.sh
drwxr-xr-x 8 pi pi  4096 Oct 10 19:02 ncp-app
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi pi  8991 Oct 10 19:02 ncp.sh
drwxr-xr-x 8 pi pi  4096 Oct 10 19:02 ncp-web
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi pi  1488 Oct 10 19:02 post-inst.sh
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi pi  4212 Oct 10 19:02 README.md
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi pi  4751 Oct 10 19:02 README-ZH-TW.md
-rwxr-xr-x 1 pi pi  3641 Oct 10 19:02 run_update_history.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 pi pi  1220 Oct 10 19:02 tag_and_push.sh
drwxr-xr-x 2 pi pi  4096 Oct 10 19:02 tests
drwxr-xr-x 2 pi pi  4096 Oct 10 19:02 updates
-rwxr-xr-x 1 pi pi  5571 Oct 10 19:02 update.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

```
pi@nextcloudpi:~ $ ./installer.sh no-ip.sh 192.168.8.114
```

You're trying to run `installer.sh` in the current directory, which is your home directory, or `/home/pi` by default (the home directory can be also referred to by `~`).

In the instructions you're following, the words *generic software installer* are actually a link to [this page](https://ownyourbits.com/2017/03/05/generic-software-installer-for-raspbian/), containing two scripts: `install.sh` and `library.sh`. For your command to work, those two scripts and the `no-ip.sh` from your original instruction link would need to already be present in your home directory, and the error message indicates at least `install.sh` is not there.

And reading the ["generic software installer" page](https://ownyourbits.com/2017/03/05/generic-software-installer-for-raspbian/), it seems that these scripts aren't even meant to run in the actual Raspbian system, but in a separate Linux system used to manage a fleet of Raspbians, or to run a Raspbian image through QEMU to prepare it with custom set-up before deploying to actual Raspbians.

I have to say one more thing. Blindly running unsigned scripts downloaded from the internet is **really stupid** in terms of security: if a malicious person ever gains write access to the ownyourbits.com blog, they might replace the script content and then anyone following the instructions after that point would be getting malware installed instead (or in addition to!) what they're expecting.

For such an installation method to be safe, you would have to **read and thoroughly understand** every script you download before running it. The very fact that you are asking this question indicates you did not do that.

I would suggest this procedure instead:

https://www.andreagrandi.it/2014/09/02/configuring-ddclient-to-update-your-dynamic-dns-at-noip-com/

This uses `sudo apt-get install ddclient`, which loads a **cryptographically signed** `ddclient` package from the standard Raspbian repositories. Even if the repository server becomes hacked, the signing keys should not be on it, and so the hacker won't be able to replace any packages with malicious ones without being detected essentially as soon as someone attempts to install a tampered-with package.